# Unparseable date with timezone and SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, grails, timezone, simpledateformat

I'm trying to build a query to be able to search in a field by date. I'm trying that I show in the code below, but I'm getting this error:

Class

```
java.text.ParseException
```

Message
Unparseable date:

```
"sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="BST",offset=21600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=8,lastRule=null]"
```

Thanks in advance

```
if (params.dateFromQuery){
                TimeZone timez = user.timeZone
                SimpleDateFormat sdfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                SimpleDateFormat sdfOut = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                String input = timez;
                Date date = sdfIn.parse(input);

                ge('startTime', sdfOut.format(date))
                params.dateFrom = sdfOut.format(date)
            }
```

Comment: `"sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="BST",offset=21600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=8,lastRule=null]"` doesn't match the pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`. It's the string representation of a timezone, not a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't parse a Date at all - you parse String representation of a timezone:

```
TimeZone timez = user.timeZone 
String input = timez; //THIS IS WRONG
Date date = sdfIn.parse(input);
```

Check where you're retrieving input from - must be somewhere in your query.

It should look like this:

```
TimeZone timez = user.timeZone 
sdfIn.setTimeZone(timez);
String input = params.dateFromQuery; //from your webform
Date date = sdfIn.parse(input);
```

If you want the TimeZone to be used in parsing/formatting you'd need to set

```
sdfIn.setTimeZone(timez);
```

Before parsing / formatting dates with that instance.

```
//Formatting time to set as 'startTime'. Which timezone to set here?
ge('startTime', sdfOut.format(date))

//Writing to input parameter?!
params.dateFrom = sdfOut.format(date)
```

Comment: Something like this: TimeZone timez = user.timeZone
    
    
    SimpleDateFormat sdfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    String input = timez;
    sdfIn.setTimeZone(timez);
    Date date = sdfIn.parse(input);
    
    ge('startTime', sdfOut.format(date))
    params.dateFrom = sdfOut.format(date) I get the same error...

Comment: String input = timez; is **EVIL**. You need input to be a String representing a date!

Comment: I try to get the input data from here in the gsp: <div class="fieldcontain">
             <label for="dateFromQuery">Date & Time From:</label>
             <jqueryPicker:time name="dateFromQuery" value="${params.dateFrom}" /> </div>

Comment: see my edit -> `input = params.dateFromQuery;` might help you.

Comment: I think that I'm close. I have now: Cannot format given Object as a Date in this line ge('startTime', sdfOut.format(input))

Comment: yes. format takes a `Date`or a `long` and converts them back to `String`. You should pass `date` there

Comment: could be whatever timezone

Comment: I think that this part is working.... I have a problem (java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date) in def results = c.list (params) {inside this brackets i have the before code} this takes all the data of the diferents search files that I have

Comment: If your question "unparseable date" is answered, please accept an answer (maybe upvote) and ask a new one for your Class-Cast-Problem, including verifiable code example.